# How to Convert FileTime to String with DateFormat

Tags: java, datetime, nio

I'm attempting to convert the creationTime attribute of a file to a string with a date format of MM/dd/yyyy.  I am using Java nio to obtain the the creationTime attribute, which is of `FileTime` type, but I just want the date from this `FileTime` as a string with the date format specified previously.  So far I have ...

```
String file = "C:\\foobar\\example.docx";
Path filepath = Paths.get(file);
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(filepath,BasicFileAttributes.class); 
FileTime date = attr.creationTime();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String dateCreated = df.format(date);
```

However, it throws an exception saying it cannot format the `FileTime date` object as a Date.  FileTime seems to output in form of `2015-01-30T17:30:57.081839Z` for example.  What solution would you recommend to best solve this?  Should I just use regex on that output or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just [get the milliseconds since epoch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html#toMillis--) from the `FileTime`.

```
String dateCreated = df.format(date.toMillis());
//                                 ^
```

Answer (score 12):

Convert FileTime to millis by `toMillis()` method.

```
String file = "C:\\foobar\\example.docx";
Path filepath = Paths.get(file);
        BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(filepath, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        FileTime date = attr.creationTime();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        String dateCreated = df.format(date.toMillis());
        System.out.println(dateCreated);
```

Use this code to get formatted value.

Answer (score 6):

In Java 8, you can convert the `FileTime` into `ZonedDateTime` before formatting it:

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
long cTime = attr.creationTime().toMillis();
ZonedDateTime t = Instant.ofEpochMilli(cTime).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
String dateCreated = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy").format(t);
System.out.println(dateCreated);
```

which prints:

```
06/05/2018
```

Comment: Instead of using `toMillis()` and then `Instant.ofEpochMillis()` you can simply use `toInstant()` of the `FileTime` class.

Comment: @cbley I initially proposed `FileTime#toInstant()` too, but then there's bug, so I changed in [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50700687/revisions). But I don't remember the reason anymore...

Comment: But you might loose precision (if the FileTime has nanosecond precision) when converting to milliseconds. I really would be interested what kind of bug there was...

Comment: @cbley and @Mi@MincongHuang `dateTimeFormatter.format(fileTime.toInstant())` throws exception `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: Year`

Comment: @VenkataRaju: If you want to format an `Instant` you have to supply a TimeZone, otherwise the formatter cannot decide how to render the information: `dateTimeFormatter.format(fileTime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)))`

Answer (score 4):

Converting FileTime to Date

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Logs\\Application.evtx");
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
try {
    BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    Date d1 = df.parse(df.format(attr.creationTime().toMillis()));
    System.out.println("File time  : " +d1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("oops error! " + e.getMessage());
}
```

use this code to convert

Answer (score 0):

To summarise:

```
String file = "C:\\foobar\\example.docx";
Path filepath = Paths.get(file);
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(filepath,BasicFileAttributes.class); 
FileTime date = attr.creationTime();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String dateCreated = df.format(date.toMillis());
```

Comment: Just change the last line on the bottom